# Are the terms "Language Implementation", "Runtime" and "Virtual Machine" synonymous?

Tags: terminology, programming-languages, python

To describe the implementation of a dynamic programming language, I have seen the terms "Runtime" (e.g. [Security transparency in the Python runtime](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0551/)), "Virtual Machine" ([Python Virtual Machine (PVM)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0330/), [YARV (Yet another Ruby VM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YARV)) and "Interpreter" ([Matz's Ruby Interpreter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_MRI)) used. JavaScript also [uses the word "Engine"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_engine).

IMO the word "Interpreter" strictly describes only *part* of a language implementation: that which steps through and executes bytecode. "Interpreter"  excludes other parts of the implementation, such as a garbage collector.

Are the other terms, "Runtime", "Virtual Machine" and "Engine" synonymous with the language implementation as a whole? Are these terms interchangeable?

Comment: I'm quite sure this is offtopic here, but not sure whether to send it to [SO] or [softwareengineering.SE]. Tending towards the latter. Opinions?

Comment: I'm sure PL implememtation is part of PL, which is on topic. I'm not sure if this is a question mainly about the theory of PL implememtation, though. Anyway the answer is NO: C, Go and Rust have runtimes but no VMs.